# Iterating through a dataframe to obtain location data from coordinates

Tags: python, pandas, geopy

I have a pandas dataframe that contains latitude and longitude and am trying to create a function to take the coordinates and determine what state each location is in. I am using geopy to obtain location information from the coordinates.

Sample data:

[image]

If I wanted just one location, the code would be as follows:

```
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='geoapiExercises')
latitude = '38.0525'
longitude = '-85.9103'
location = geolocator.reverse(latitude + ',' + longitude)
address = location.raw['address']
state = address.get('state', '')
```

However, I have around 10,000 coordinates that I need to find the state for. I have tried my hand at iterating over the dataframe using a for loop, but I'll admit I'm not the best at it. My current function returns a ValueError.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

df = pd.read_csv('filepath.csv')
us_df = df.loc[df['country_name'] == 'United States of America']

def state(df):
    for row in df:
        # get lat & long
        latitude = str(df['latitude'])
        longitude = str(df['longitude'])
        
        geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='geoapiExercises')
        location = geolocator.reverse(latitude + ',' + longitude)
        address = location.raw['address']
        state = address.get('state', '')
        df['state'] = state
        
state(us_df)
```

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Python3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/geopy/geocoders/nominatim.py:350, in Nominatim.reverse(self, query, exactly_one, timeout, language, addressdetails, zoom, namedetails)
    349 try:
--> 350     lat, lon = self._coerce_point_to_string(query).split(',')
    351 except ValueError:

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Python3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/geopy/geocoders/base.py:300, in Geocoder._coerce_point_to_string(self, point, output_format)
    299 if not isinstance(point, Point):
--> 300     point = Point(point)
    302 # Altitude is silently dropped.
    303 #
    304 # Geocoding services (almost?) always consider only lat and lon
   (...)
    307 # though, because PoIs are assumed to span the whole
    308 # altitude axis (i.e. not just the 0km plane).

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Python3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/geopy/point.py:166, in Point.__new__(cls, latitude, longitude, altitude)
    165 elif isinstance(arg, str):
--> 166     return cls.from_string(arg)
    167 else:

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Python3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/geopy/point.py:457, in Point.from_string(cls, string)
    456 else:
--> 457     raise ValueError(
    458         "Failed to create Point instance from string: unknown format."
    459     )

ValueError: Failed to create Point instance from string: unknown format.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[15], line 17
     14         state = address.get('state', '')
     15         df['state'] = state
---> 17 city_state(us_df)        

Cell In[15], line 12, in city_state(df)
      9 longitude = str(df['longitude'])
     11 geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='geoapiExercises')
---> 12 location = geolocator.reverse(latitude + ',' + longitude)
     13 address = location.raw['address']
     14 state = address.get('state', '')

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Python3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/geopy/geocoders/nominatim.py:352, in Nominatim.reverse(self, query, exactly_one, timeout, language, addressdetails, zoom, namedetails)
    350     lat, lon = self._coerce_point_to_string(query).split(',')
    351 except ValueError:
--> 352     raise ValueError("Must be a coordinate pair or Point")
    353 params = {
    354     'lat': lat,
    355     'lon': lon,
    356     'format': 'json',
    357 }
    358 if language:

ValueError: Must be a coordinate pair or Point
```

It says the value must be a coordinate, so I must not be iterating correctly. Any help is appreciated.

I am using Python 3.10

Edit: When using the iterrows() solution below, a TimeoutError is returned:

```
TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Python3.10/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py:1348, in AbstractHTTPHandler.do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1347 try:
-> 1348     h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
   1349               encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
   1350 except OSError as err: # timeout error

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Python3.10/lib/python3.10/http/client.py:1282, in HTTPConnection.request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1281 """Send a complete request to the server."""
-> 1282 self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Python3.10/lib/python3.10/http/client.py:1328, in HTTPConnection._send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1327     body = _encode(body, 'body')
-> 1328 self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Python3.10/lib/python3.10/http/client.py:1277, in HTTPConnection.endheaders(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1276     raise CannotSendHeader()
-> 1277 self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Python3.10/lib/python3.10/http/client.py:1037, in HTTPConnection._send_output(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1036 del self._buffer[:]
-> 1037 self.send(msg)
   1039 if message_body is not None:
   1040 
   1041     # create a consistent interface to message_body

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Python3.10/lib/python3.10/http/client.py:975, in HTTPConnection.send(self, data)
    974 if self.auto_open:
--> 975     self.connect()
    976 else:

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Python3.10/lib/python3.10/http/client.py:1454, in HTTPSConnection.connect(self)
   1452     server_hostname = self.host
-> 1454 self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
   1455                                       server_hostname=server_hostname)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Python3.10/lib/python3.10/ssl.py:513, in SSLContext.wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, session)
    507 def wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side=False,
    508                 do_handshake_on_connect=True,
    509                 suppress_ragged_eofs=True,
    510                 server_hostname=None, session=None):
    511     # SSLSocket class handles server_hostname encoding before it calls
    512     # ctx._wrap_socket()
--> 513     return self.sslsocket_class._create(
    514         sock=sock,
    515         server_side=server_side,
    516         do_handshake_on_connect=do_handshake_on_connect,
    517         suppress_ragged_eofs=suppress_ragged_eofs,
    518         server_hostname=server_hostname,
    519         context=self,
    520         session=session
    521     )

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Python3.10/lib/python3.10/ssl.py:1071, in SSLSocket._create(cls, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, context, session)
   1070             raise ValueError("do_handshake_on_connect should not be specified for non-blocking sockets")
-> 1071         self.do_handshake()
   1072 except (OSError, ValueError):

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Python3.10/lib/python3.10/ssl.py:1342, in SSLSocket.do_handshake(self, block)
   1341         self.settimeout(None)
-> 1342     self._sslobj.do_handshake()
   1343 finally:

TimeoutError: _ssl.c:980: The handshake operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

URLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Python3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/geopy/adapters.py:297, in URLLibAdapter.get_text(self, url, timeout, headers)
    296 try:
--> 297     page = self.urlopen(req, timeout=timeout)
    298 except Exception as error:

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Python3.10/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py:519, in OpenerDirector.open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    518 sys.audit('urllib.Request', req.full_url, req.data, req.headers, req.get_method())
--> 519 response = self._open(req, data)
    521 # post-process response

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Python3.10/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py:536, in OpenerDirector._open(self, req, data)
    535 protocol = req.type
--> 536 result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
    537                           '_open', req)
    538 if result:

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Python3.10/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py:496, in OpenerDirector._call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    495 func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 496 result = func(*args)
    497 if result is not None:

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Python3.10/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py:1391, in HTTPSHandler.https_open(self, req)
   1390 def https_open(self, req):
-> 1391     return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
   1392         context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Python3.10/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py:1351, in AbstractHTTPHandler.do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1350 except OSError as err: # timeout error
-> 1351     raise URLError(err)
   1352 r = h.getresponse()

URLError: <urlopen error _ssl.c:980: The handshake operation timed out>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

GeocoderTimedOut                          Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[16], line 17
     14         state = address.get('state', '')
     15         df.at[index, 'state'] = state
---> 17 city_state(us_df)        

Cell In[16], line 12, in city_state(df)
      9 longitude = str(row['longitude'])
     11 geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='geoapiExercises')
---> 12 location = geolocator.reverse(latitude + ',' + longitude)
     13 address = location.raw['address']
     14 state = address.get('state', '')

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Python3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/geopy/geocoders/nominatim.py:372, in Nominatim.reverse(self, query, exactly_one, timeout, language, addressdetails, zoom, namedetails)
    370 logger.debug("%s.reverse: %s", self.__class__.__name__, url)
    371 callback = partial(self._parse_json, exactly_one=exactly_one)
--> 372 return self._call_geocoder(url, callback, timeout=timeout)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Python3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/geopy/geocoders/base.py:368, in Geocoder._call_geocoder(self, url, callback, timeout, is_json, headers)
    366 try:
    367     if is_json:
--> 368         result = self.adapter.get_json(url, timeout=timeout, headers=req_headers)
    369     else:
    370         result = self.adapter.get_text(url, timeout=timeout, headers=req_headers)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Python3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/geopy/adapters.py:286, in URLLibAdapter.get_json(self, url, timeout, headers)
    285 def get_json(self, url, *, timeout, headers):
--> 286     text = self.get_text(url, timeout=timeout, headers=headers)
    287     try:
    288         return json.loads(text)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Python3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/geopy/adapters.py:315, in URLLibAdapter.get_text(self, url, timeout, headers)
    313 elif isinstance(error, URLError):
    314     if "timed out" in message:
--> 315         raise GeocoderTimedOut("Service timed out")
    316     elif "unreachable" in message:
    317         raise GeocoderUnavailable("Service not available")

GeocoderTimedOut: Service timed out
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of ```df = pd.read_csv('filepath.csv')```?

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes I figured latitude and longitude columns were enough. I have edited my post to include the info you requested.

Comment: Have you tried the solution I proposed?

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes Yes, I just tried it. This time I get a TimeoutError. I actually tried itertuples() as well and got the same error. I've read where you can specify a `timeout` value, but this seemed to freeze the program when I ran it. I will edit the post with this error.

Comment: Check if changing the timeout value helps. Check my updated nswer

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes Looks like this is working, but Nominatim doesn't seem to like how many rows there are so it is taking a very long time. Trying this before I figured the kernel froze up, but now I tried with a smaller snippet of the dataframe and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not having a sample of your data makes it hard to troubleshoot, but I think the issue is with the way you are accessing the values of the latitude and longitude in the dataframe.
You are using `for row in df` and you are iterating over the rows of the dataframe as series, not the values of the latitude and longitude columns.

So, to get the values of the latitude and longitude for each row, you should use the `iterrows()` method on the dataframe.

So, I think you should try this instead (but as I stated in my comment, data would be useful)

```
def state(df):
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        # get lat & long
        latitude = str(row['latitude'])
        longitude = str(row['longitude'])
        
        geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='geoapiExercises')
        location = geolocator.reverse(latitude + ',' + longitude)
        address = location.raw['address']
        state = address.get('state', '')
        df.at[index, 'state'] = state
```

If it times out use this:

```
def state(df):
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        # get lat & long
        latitude = str(row['latitude'])
        longitude = str(row['longitude'])
        
        geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='geoapiExercises', timeout=10)
        location = geolocator.reverse(latitude + ',' + longitude)
        address = location.raw['address']
        state = address.get('state', '')
        df.at[index, 'state'] = state
```

where you can adjust the timeout value